# Reseize grid columns CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a problem with two columns. I am trying to place a column next to the other but I am missing something. The idea is to get fully responsive columns, which will look like a column on the desktop and columns one under another on a mobile. I am really lost. I do not have any idea what else to do. I would really appreciate any help!

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
          <div class="container1">

             <img src="img/image.jpg" class="picture1">

                <div class="about">
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-3half">
                    
                        <div class="title">
                            <a class="arrow"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="previousPages">ALL PRODUCTS / HAIRCARE</a>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

My grid has the class "container1" holding my two columns, "img" with the class called "picture1" and a container  "about".

CSS:

```
.container1{
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 910px 516px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 14px;
    gap: 0rem;

    font-family: 'Lato';

}

.picture1{
    display: flex;
    width: 910px;
    height: 770px;
}

.about{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 770px;
    width: 516px;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #F7F6F5;
}

.col-sm-3half{
    width: 396px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.title{
    display: flex;
    width: 360px;
    height: 61px;
    margin-bottom: 59px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 2px;  /* 45px + 2px */
}

.arrow{
    display: flex;
    width: 14px;
    height: 9px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    background: url(img/arrow.png);

}

.previousPages{
    display: flex;
    width: 348px;
    height: 61px;
    left: 995px;
    top: 23px;

    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 159.1%;

    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-decoration: none;

    color: #4D4D4D;

}
```

I am not sure if my problem is with the attribute `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax());` or `display` attribute.

CodeSandBox (link): shorturl.at/IOPR5

Comment: Your link isnt working

Answer (score 0):

i thing you must set at view mobile

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .container{
   grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added the @media and it is working on mobile (columns are one under the other). But I still struggle trying to place a column next to the other one. Thanks also for you help!

Comment: you can use 

grid-template-columns: 70% 30%; or grid-template-columns: 70% auto;

Comment: I just did it but It doesn't work. Appartently I need to use  `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax()) ` in order to get the responsive work. But somehow my colums doesn't stand in the right position. I left the link of the project if you wanna check it out.

Comment: the problem I thing at .about, maybe you can see my code in this link playground
https://codepen.io/rentomz/pen/OJEpaGK

Comment: The box container next to the picture overflows the picture. I have no idea and I am loosing it.